# iOS - How to iterate through list of files on website directory

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlrequest

On iOS, I am looking for the proper way to return the URLs for a list of files that are in a directory.

```
/images
    1.jpg
    2.jpg
    3.jpg
    ...
```

I know the URL for the directory and know all the files in the directory will be of type jpeg. It is not clear to me how to properly format the NSURLRequest to return the list of files in the images directory. Once the list is returned, I will iterate through it to return the individual images.

Comment: First iterate through your questions and send an `- [NSStackOverflowAnswer accept];` message to whichever answer helped you.

Comment: Have you tried doing a normal request with the URL "http://www.website.com/images"? If the server has directory browsing active (must be for you to do listing) you should get a list of the files (it should be HTML formatted, but you can extract easily).